# Ensure integrity of other columns from foreign record

Tags: mysql, postgresql, referential-integrity

I have 3 tables:

```
Race
 - id PK

Racer
 - id PK
 - rank

Winner
 - id PK
 - race_id FK(Race.id)
 - racer_id FK(Racer.id)
 - rank
 - prize
 UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (race_id, rank)
```

`Racer.rank` is a non-unique values, as some players can tie to a rank. I try to have records in `Winner` to have its `rank` match the `Racer.rank` that it references to. The unique constraint is to ensure that each race has only one 1st place.

The integrity between `Winner.rank` and `Racer.rank` is to enforcing if we later update `Racer.rank`, we will have to update the value in `Winner` as well, or remove that `Winner` row. How can I enforce that matching?

Other separate question:
- Is there a keyword that describe what I try to accomplish? I try to search with "referential integrity", "foreign constraint non-unique"... but none gets me to satified result.

Comment: i can't understand, you want to save in the winner table the rank of the t´winner at that time, if not don't save it in winner tabe its redundant.

Comment: Please post ddl (including Keys)

Comment: Why do you need winner.rank? You can derive that from razer |X| winner?

Comment: Since racer.id is unique so is racer.id+racer.rank. I.e you can declare this as unique and reference that in winner. But as mentioned above, why denormalize rank?

Comment: Thanks @Lennart and @nbk for helping me. `Winner.rank` is indeed a redundant column, that I hope to help me enforcing only 1 player of a given rank x per race. For clarifying, do you mean I should set (`racer.id` & `racer.rank`) as a foreign key in `Winner`? It indeed seems like a good solution.

Comment: Yes, I'll add an example in answer

Comment: @bizi, I added the content of above comments to my answer. But re-reading the question makes me wonder why rank is part of racer? Winner (or Result as I called it) seems the most appropriate place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough sketch of the comments:

```
CREATE TABLE Race
( Race_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  -- I prefer to use the same name through out the model
);

CREATE TABLE Racer
( Racer_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  -- See above
, Rank INT NOT NULL
,   CONSTRAINT AK1_Racer UNIQUE (Rank, Racer_id) -- Super key
);

CREATE TABLE Result  -- Is not "Result" a better name than Winner?
-- I removed id
( Race_id INT NOT NULL
, Racer_id INT NOT NULL
, Rank INT NOT NULL  -- See below
, ...   
,   CONSTRAINT PK_Result PRIMARY KEY (Race_id, Racer_id)
,   CONSTRAINT AK_Result UNIQUE (Race_id, Rank)
,   CONSTRAINT FK_Race FOREIGN KEY (Race_id)
                       REFERENCES Race (Race_id)
,   CONSTRAINT FK_Racer FOREIGN KEY (Rank, Racer_id)
                       REFERENCES Racer (Rank, Race_id)
);
```

EDIT:

I'm not sure why RANK is part of RACER. It seems like all kinds of possible ranks can be derived from WINNER (RESULT):

```
SELECT Racer_id
     , COUNT(1) as #races
     , AVG(Rank) as avg_rank
     , MIN(Rank) as lowest_rank
     , MAX(Rank) as highest_rank
     , ...
FROM Result -- Winner
GROUP BY Racer_id
```

If there is some other metric like score, time, etc that determines the rank per race, you may also consider storing that and derive rank from there. PostgreSQL and newer versions of MySQL have window functions like RANK() that is very useful for such calculations.

Comment: `rank` needs to go into `result`, as the rank depends on the race, not the racer. Otherwise it's impossible to store the ranks of a single racer in two different races.

Comment: Yes, I realized that when I was adding the answer. I'm not sure why rank is part of racer

Comment: Out side of this question, my "Racer" is actually like "Racer_Race" join table, and similar to what you think of Result. So, the real database is like Race, Result, Racer, Winner, where winner hold record for prize. The real database hold too many pieces, and I decide to abstract to its simplest form that represent my question. I am sorry if this simplifying causes confusion for you.

Comment: The level of detail you provide in your answer exceeds all my expectation when I decide to reach out for help. You even recommend the RANK function, which I didn't know about. This is really a great help for me. Thank you!